# Rails 3, root name in children list (manufacturer name in products list)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have manufacturer and product model:

```
    class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :products
    end
```

and

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :manufacturer
    end
```

Product table has manufacturer_id, i have drop-down list with manufacturer name, but in list or show i see manufacturer id, not name, how to do, what i could see name of manufacturer

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up wanting to do something like:

```
product.manufacturer.name
```

every time you want to see the manufacturer name.  Calling 'product.manufacturer' gets you the actual Manufacturer model pointed to by manufacturer_id, so you need to be specific about what aspect of it you want to see.

As for getting the name to show up in dropdowns, that's a matter of specifying both the display text and the value to use on the dropdown.  Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) for the full syntax.  Basically, you end up making an array of arrays to represent your options, where each array is made up of [name, id].

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `belongs_to` on the other end of that `has_many`...

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

And if you want help with your `<select>`, you should share that code.